# Partially applied functions and type inference in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

I have been experimenting with partialy applied functions and such a thing happened. Suppose we have such code:

```
class Color(name:String) {
override def toString = name
}

class Point(x: Int, y:Int) {
override def toString:String = "("+x +"," + y + ")"
 }

class Linestyle(name: String) {
override def toString = name
 }

def drawLine(width:Double, color: Color, style: Linestyle, a:Point, b: Point): Unit = {
println("Draw " + width + " " + color + " " + style + " " + " line from point: " + a +  " to point " + b)
}
```

When I try to create drawSolidLine function which takes only 4 parameters in such a way:

```
def drawSolidLine (c: Color, a:Point, b: Point):Unit =
drawLine(1.0, _:Color, new Linestyle("SOLID"), _:Point, _:Point)
```

and try to call it

```
drawSolidLine(2.5, new Color("Black"),new Point(2,4), new Point(3,1))
```

I have no compiler errors, but the call returns nothing.

On the other hand, when I create drawSolidLine this way:

```
val drawSolidLine = drawLine(_:Double, _:Color, new Linestyle("SOLID"),
                            _:Point, _:Point)
```

and call it before, I have the desired output:

```
Draw 1.0 Black SOLID  line from point: (2,4) to point (3,1)
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing two very different things. First:

```
def drawSolidLine (c: Color, a:Point, b: Point):Unit =
  drawLine(1.0, _:Color, new Linestyle("SOLID"), _:Point, _:Point)
```

First, notice that none of the parameters you passed are being used. The expression `drawLine(1.0, _:Color, new Linestyle("SOLID"), _:Point, :Point)` is a function which does not depend on the parameters passed, and which *would* be returned, except your return type is `Unit`. That being the case, the function is discarded.

Second:

```
val drawSolidLine = drawLine(_:Double, _:Color, new Linestyle("SOLID"),
                             _:Point, _:Point)
```

First, you can replace `val` with `def` and it will work the same. *Val vs def is not the issue*.

So, `drawSolidLine` will, since it's type is not `Unit`, return that same function. This time, however, `(2.5, new Color("Black"),new Point(2,4), new Point(3,1))` is not being passed to `drawSolidLine`, because it takes no parameters. So they'll be passed to the function that is being returned, causing the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I mixed some points in my head((. As I see now, I can write def drawThinBlackSolidLine(a:Point, b:Point):Unit =
drawLine(1.0, new Color("Black"), new Linestyle("SOLID"), a, b) and get what I want without using partial application at all. Or write def drawThinBlackSolidLine2 = drawLine(1.0, new Color("Black"), new Linestyle("SOLID"), _:Point, _:Point) without direct type specification for input parameters of drawThinBlackSolidLine2.Or there is some other way(I am just wondering:)) ?

Comment: @ferbolg That's pretty much it. You can write the latter in a different way, or you could curry the parameters of the former, but the essence is the same.